# Sorting Dictionary on two values in swift

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I have the following dictionary like so:

```
 ["FLBEY023": ["Position": 8, "Page": 1],
 "COSMAX826": ["Position": 6, "Page": 2],
 "TOVIC029": ["Position": 7, "Page": 1],
 "CGLYN188": ["Position": 2, "Page": 2],
 "TOORL002B": ["Position": 1, "Page": 2],
 "GSTOGFU096": ["Position": 6, "Page": 1],
 "COSNAI423": ["Position": 2, "Page": 1],
 "COSCOL681": ["Position": 3, "Page": 2],
 "TONIV170": ["Position": 4, "Page": 1],
 "SUMAL086A": ["Position": 7, "Page": 2],
 "PEIAM004": ["Position": 5, "Page": 1],
 "FOSCI012": ["Position": 1, "Page": 1],
 "FOSWI009": ["Position": 4, "Page": 2],
 "GSTODOV061": ["Position": 3, "Page": 1]]
```

Now I'd like to sort this Dictionary for each of the product codes. But I'd like to sort it on position and page. So for example I'd like it to run position then page number for example

```
["FOSCI012": ["Position": 1, "Page": 1],
"COSNAI423": ["Position": 2, "Page": 1],
"GSTODOV061": ["Position": 3, "Page": 1],
....
...
...
"TOORL002B": ["Position": 1, "Page": 2],
"CGLYN188": ["Position": 2, "Page": 2],
..
```

How would I go about doing this using the `Dictionary.sorted` method. I understand how to do it to sort based on one element but not two.

Comment: Dictionary don't have any order.

Comment: Given your inner dictionaries have static keys, they should be instances of a given `struct` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered collections and you can't sort them.

However, you can use [`.sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted) method that returns a list of ordered tuples where each one represents a key-value entry in the dictionary:

```
dictionary.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in

  if (lhs.value["Page"]! == rhs.value["Page"]!) {
    return lhs.value["Position"]! < rhs.value["Position"]!
  } else {
    return lhs.value["Page"]! < rhs.value["Page"]!
  }
}
```

which results in sth like below:

```
[(key: "FOSCI012", value: ["Position": 1, "Page": 1]), 
 (key: "COSNAI423", value: ["Position": 2, "Page": 1]),
 ...
 (key: "TOORL002B", value: ["Position": 1, "Page": 2]), 
 (key: "CGLYN188", value: ["Position": 2, "Page": 2]),
 ...
]
```

Here you can [download the playground](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2d24dhe9ka8gdm7/AABrtKkcYuzfXMBU2ROibjrga?dl=0).

Comment: Perfect. Works a treat for what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Little bit improvement, first consider Position then Page.

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam this would result in a wrong order. PO wants to sort entries by page first, then by position.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever Can you please brief logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort dictionary by key and value

```
extension Dictionary where Value:Comparable {
  var sortedByValue:[(Key,Value)] {return Array(dict).sorted{$0.1 < $1.1}}
}

extension Dictionary where Key:Comparable {
 var sortedByKey:[(Key,Value)] {return Array(dict).sorted{$0.0 < $1.0}}
} 

["b":2,"a":1,"c":3].sortedByKey// output will be a:1, b:2, c:3
["b":2,"a":1,"c":3].sortedByValue//output will be a:1, b:2, c:3
```